# How I can return the max product that was sold by city?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have products that were sold by city how I can return the max product that was sold by city??

This's my query :

I did the sum of the quantities for each product to have a single value of the quantity by product.

```
select
product,
sum(qty_city_o) as qty_o,
sum(qty_city_t) as qty_t,
sum(qty_city_th) as qty_th
FROM products
GROUP BY product
```

Comment: use `max` instead of `sum`

Comment: @vkp the same product can be sold many times that's why I do the sum fto return a single quantity value by product.

Comment: i don't see a `city` column mentioned anywhere.

Comment: qty_city_o,qty_city_t,qty_city_th

Comment: Can you provide some sample data along with expected result? As it stands it is unclear what you are actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do it for each city as separate query.
Something like:

```
SELECT qty_city_o, COUNT(product) FROM products GROUP BY qty_city_o ORDER BY COUNT(product) DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you max sold product for each city:

```
SELECT 'city_o', A.* FROM (SELECT 
    product, productcount
FROM
    (SELECT 
        product, COUNT(product) productcount
    FROM
        products
    WHERE
        qty_city_o > 0
    GROUP BY product) B
ORDER BY productcount DESC
LIMIT 1 ) A
UNION ALL
SELECT 'city_t', A.* FROM (SELECT 
    product, productcount
FROM
    (SELECT 
        product, COUNT(product) productcount
    FROM
        products
    WHERE
        qty_city_t > 0
    GROUP BY product) B
ORDER BY productcount DESC
LIMIT 1 ) A
UNION ALL
SELECT 'city_th', A.* FROM (SELECT 
    product, productcount
FROM
    (SELECT 
        product, COUNT(product) productcount
    FROM
        products
    WHERE
        qty_city_th > 0
    GROUP BY product) B
ORDER BY productcount DESC
LIMIT 1) A;
```